# Exporting FTP/SFTP Connections with passwords from Aptana

Tags: aptana

Aptana allows you to export preferences, project sets and also Remote Connections. However, when I export and import into a new Aptana install on another machine, the Remote Connections do display but the passwords are no longer saved.
Is there some way around this?

I have tried copying the connections file in `/Aptana Project Space/.metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.core.io` but with no joy.